# python turtle goto not allowing a negative float

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am trying to use "turtle" to show the position of the International Space Station (ISS) on a world map. I have taken the longitude and latitude from an API. Then saved the coordinates to the variables "lon" and "lat".

But when I use `iss.goto(lon, lat)` I receive a TypeError. I believe this is caused by longitude and latitude coordinates sometimes being negatives, so the float is prefixed by "-".

Could anyone please help me fix this?

```
import tkinter
import turtle
import json
import urllib.request

url = 'http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json'
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
result = json.loads(response.read())

location = result['iss_position']
lat = (location['latitude'])
lon = (location['longitude'])
print('latitude: ', lat)
print('longitude: ', lon)

screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(3000, 1500)
screen.setworldcoordinates(-180, -90, 180, 90)
screen.register_shape('iss2.gif')

screen.bgpic('world_map.png')

iss = turtle.Turtle()
iss.shape('iss2.gif')
iss.setheading(90)
iss.penup()

iss.goto(lon, lat) #  I get the error here

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Ouch/PycharmProjects/Learning/Space_station.py", line 47, in     <module>
iss.goto(lon, lat)
File "C:\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 1776, in goto
self._goto(Vec2D(x, y))
File "C:\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 3165, in _goto
diff = (end-start)
File "C:\Python37\lib\turtle.py", line 262, in __sub__
return Vec2D(self[0]-other[0], self[1]-other[1])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'float'
```

Comment: try `print(type(lat))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is complaining that you can't subtract a float from a string.

So, the problem has nothing to do with some of the values being floats, or some of the floats being negative. You can't subtract an int from a string, or a positive float from a string, or anything else from a string. The problem is that some of your values are strings.

You can see this if you print out the repr of the values rather than the values directly:

```
print('latitude: ', repr(lat))
print('longitude: ', repr(lon))
```

You'll see something like this:

```
latitude:  '-10.4958'
longitude:  '-172.9960'
```

So, to fix this, just convert those strings to floats:

```
lat = float(location['latitude'])
lon = float(location['longitude'])
```